# boost problems 1.55 skipped 8 targets

Tags: c++, boost, installation

When i open cmd i write.

```
cd /d (root)  
bootstrap.bat  
.\b2 --prefix=(root/newone)
```

After 1 minute processing a have this.

failed updating 8 targets
skiped 8 targets

How to install correct?

Comment: Well, what 8 targets? And why? It seems likely that `b2` is giving more error output than this -- paste that.

Comment: http://cs409622.vk.me/v409622011/503c/gF2Z7kdDF9Y.jpg

Comment: Post the relevant error messages as text within the question, in a code tag.

Comment: I can't cause a have 1 reputation. sorry. in screenshot all that i have after start building

Comment: So can someone help me? i very want to try asio library

Comment: Boost building is a tragedy.  Been a while since I last saw a clean build.  Just keep your fingers crossed that you don't actually need them to link.  Probably not.

Comment: link.jam no such file or directory  in begin of build. What do u think?

Comment: 1.55 won't build [with msvc12](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20265157/unable-to-use-boost-libraries-in-vs2013-for-c).