# Unable to use boost libraries in vs2013 for C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, boost

I have extracted boost_1_55_0 to my C disk (directly), then, I used console (as admin) to run bootstrap and then .\b2. After all that (and a long time), everything was done. Then, I opened my project, pushed the properties on my project and for C++ tab I included additional library (C:\boost_1_55_0), disable precompiled headers and in linkers general settings, I added addidtional library (C:\boost_1_55_0\stage\lib).

My program runs just fine if I am not including anything from boost, but just when I do (for ex, I tried including #include ), it stops compiling and says

> C:\boost_1_55_0\boost/exception/exception.hpp(161): error C2955: 'std::set' : use of class template requires template argument list

and

> C:\boost_1_55_0\boost/exception/exception.hpp(161): error C2838: 'set' : illegal qualified name in member declaration

Any ideas whats going on? I am not using any boost functions, I am just trying to include one boost library.

EDIT:
I trimmed my main.cpp compeltely (only left one boost include and main class itself). Now it says that it is unable to access .lib file. I use windows 8.1 64bit. I think I am done with this OS, since it is so messed up when it comes to admin rights.

Comment: Consider add [minimal code example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)

Comment: Note that there are known issues using [Boost and VS2013](http://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_55_0.html). Without seeing your code we don't know if you're simply seeing one of these.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Boost 1.55 does not support VS 2013 yet.

Quoting the [release notes](http://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_55_0.html):

> Visual Studio 2013 was released quite late in the release process, so
>   there exist several unresolved issues.

So unless you are willing to patch Boost yourself, you will probably have to wait for the next Boost release.

Comment: Ohh. Thanks. I guess its time to download visual studio 2012 :)

Comment: I just installed VS2012 and I get the same errors. Whats the problem?